# CSS: How to make the border of a <p> tag to be 100 percent on the div tag?

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I am using boostrap for my website and I want a border to take the whole width of a specific div. This is what I have so far:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/bcijc2g2j/]

and I want to make it on the whole div. I tried `display:block width:100%`, it just doesn't want to work.

Anyone for a solution ?

#### CSS

```
.borders {
    border-top: 1px solid #dedbdb;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col md-4 borders">
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>{numberAttending} {numberMaybe} {numberNotAttending}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be taking up 100% of the div here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhUJs/ Is there some other CSS that could be affecting it that you didn't include in your post? Margins or padding maybe?

Comment: The parent DIV has to have some sort of apdding on it. P and Div tags will default to 100% width since they are blocks. The "row" must have padding.

Comment: well guys I am using boostrap... I guess there is where hte padding is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your border is not taking up the entire width is because your row has padding on it.

```
<div class="row no-padding">
     <div class="col md-4 my-styles">
        <p><Content here.</p>
     </div>
</div>

.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}

.my-styles {
    border-top: 1px solid #dedbdb;
    padding: 15px;
}
```